# Jupyter Interface Refresh by Background Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, widget, jupyter, jupyter-lab

```
import threading
import IPython
import ipywidgets
import time
from   tqdm.auto import tqdm

output = ipywidgets.Output(layout=ipywidgets.Layout(border='2px solid gray'))
display(output)

def work():
    with globals()['output']:
        progress = ipywidgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=1.0)
        button   = ipywidgets.Button(description="push!")
        def on_clique(b): 
            with globals()['output']: print("The user accessed gui.")
        button.on_click(on_clique)
        display(progress, button)
        for i in tqdm(range(10)):
            time.sleep(1)
            print("The background thread accessed gui: ", i)
            progress.value = float(i+1)/10

thread = threading.Thread(target=work, daemon=True)
thread.start()

while True: time.sleep(1) # Execution flow retainment instruction
```

- Please do run this code on JupyterLab, notice that while the background thread can and does access the widgets, the user can not enjoy using the button.
- Remove the “Execution flow retainment instruction” and restart the kernel and run again, this time notice that while the user can use the button, the interface accessing capabilities of the background thread are highly limited.
- A question arises: WTF?! Why can’t they just access the widgets at the same time? how to programmatically choose about which one will access at any given moment? How to have the user enjoying the interface while the automated procedure being able to completely refresh it at any given moment if needed? (without user intervention)
- In order to remove the bottlenecks of a better automation, an improvised workaroud is required, please let me know of your valuable ideas on the matter.

Comment: Please let us focus our energy on real workaround solutions, condemning the problem doesn’t isn't a solution ;)

Common Unhelpful Approaches:
* Why do you ask such a question? What are you trying to do? You must not even think like that!
* So basically what you are asking for is in direct contradiction with the Heisenberg’s Third Law of Blue JupyterNotebooking: E=mc^2, please educate your self first before posting questions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations.
* I have absolutely no idea about, but here is how you visuallize a Matrix in MATLAB: https://www.example.com

Comment: Example Productive Answers:
* You may be able to eliminate the need for automated outputing by widgets generation, and instead use a static combination of widgets and content driven output. Replace the ipywidgets.Output with ipywidgets.HTML and so on. Unfortunately this doesn’t satisfy all the use cases.
* Find some mechanism to make a frequenting trigger on the main thread, like programmatically execute an empty cell once in a while, in order to somehow keep the gui updating processes active. Though unclean but feasible.

Comment: * The clean approach, know the Jupyter ecosystem well in details, through its modules somehow programmatically modify its configurations to behave the desired way.

Comment: THIS PROBLEM ONLY HAPPENS ON JUPYTER_LAB, THE GOOD OLD JUPYTER NOTEBOOKS DO THINGS JUST FINE.